# How can I remove an *extremely* stubborn driver in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I recently bought a pen tablet to replace an old Wacom Bamboo that wasn't working correctly anymore. I've read having multiple tablet drivers can cause issues so I tried removing the Wacom drivers but so far I've been unable to completely remove the stubborn thing no matter what I tried. I've already searched the net for possible solutions and tried the following :

- Run `uninstall` from the applications settings page of course. The uninstaller exited with an error telling me the applications was already uninstalled which I knew was wrong.
- Uninstall the device in `device manager`. At least it no longer shows there.
- Use [Driver Store Explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer) to remove Wacom drivers from the driver store. I still have a file named `wacompen.sys` in `System32\Drivers` and `System32\DriverStore` as well as several Wacom references in the Registry at that point.
- Try to clean up the Driver Store again, this time using `PnPUtil` in administrative PowerShell without better success.
- Manually remove `wacompen.sys` using explorer and administrative PowerShell without any success (I get an error message telling me I need authorization from `TrustedInstaller` to proceed)
- Manually delete the registry keys without any success (I get error messages)
- Try again after restarting in `Diagnostic Mode`, still no success.
- Use Windows 10 `Fresh Start` function! `wacompen.sys` and the registry keys are still there after my system was supposedly `reset to factory default`, and no the Bamboo didn't come with my computer. BTW it's wasn't the only driver left-over after the procedure.

The last thing I can think of right now that I didn't try is "format C:" but before nuking my system drive I'd like to be sure there's really no other option, especially since I'm not sure how I'll be able to reinstall windows after that given my copy is an update from 8 that was updated from pre-installed 7 so I don't have any license key anywhere.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tried an awful lot of things, but was there ever any actual problem to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and I was able to use the [Driver Store Explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer) you mentioned to remove the last vestiges of my old Wacom driver. When I first tried the deletion it displayed an error about the driver being in use, but I knew for a fact it wasn't so I used the "Force" option checkbox. Then the deletion worked fine. (Perhaps that's a new feature since you posted this question?)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to download trial license of [Revo Uninstaller Pro](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install it.

After the installation open the application and click on `Force Uninstall` type the name of the program/registry or leftover application name to force uninstall it. It also helps you to remove registry of related application.

Then, download [device cleanup tool](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html) to remove non-present drivers from your system. (Make sure to run `Run as administrator`)

This should fix your problem but if you want to take more additional step to make sure you are free from other registries as well. You can download [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard), install it and open it.

Click to `Registry` then `Scan for Issues` and `Fix Selected Issues`

That's it. You should be good to go. As for your updated Windows 10 operating system from 8 (or 7) since, Microsoft stores your CPU data in their database you don't need the license key anymore. It'll automatically activate the Windows for you but just make sure your are using the same version of Windows(eg. Professional, Single Language etc)